# How do I access individual values within a string array within a Hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap, arrays

My declaration of the map is as follows:

```
Map<Integer, String[]> mapVar = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();
```

And I initialized it by making several string arrays and putting them into my map with a corresponding Integer.

I would like to then Iterate through all of the elements in my String array within the map.
I tried these two possiblities but they're not giving me the right values:

```
for(int ii =0; ii < 2; ii++)
  System.out.println(((HashMap<Integer, String[]>)mapVar).values().toArray()[ii].toString());
```

and

```
mapVar.values().toString();
```

I also know the array and Integer are going into the map fine, I just don't know how to access them.

Thanks

Comment: What are your inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs?

Comment: The strings "13", "26" and "14", "28" I get [Ljava.lang.String;@342798e7 and [Ljava.lang.String;@13a78071

Comment: That's the default `toString()` representation of a `String[]`. You want to print the individual Strings, not the array object's `toString()`. See my answer.

Comment: before you go all happy building a datastructure with hashmaps and arrays only, consider creating classes for the data you want to hold with appropriate implementations of hashCode and equals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
for (String[] value : mapvar.values()) {
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(value));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (String[] strings : mapVar.values()) {
  for (String str : strings) {
     System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

That will print all of the `Strings` in all of the arrays in the `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String[]> entry : mapVar.entrySet()) {
   for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
      // do whatever
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access *all* the `String` values in the map as one unit rather than dealing with the intermediate arrays, I'd suggest using a [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html):

```
ListMultimap<Integer, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
// put stuff in the multimap
for (String string : multimap.values()) { ... } // all strings in the multimap
```

Of course you can also access the list of `String`s associated with a particular key:

```
List<String> valuesFor1 = multimap.get(1);
```